# breaking output of php array into chunks

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array containing information about some images, which I am using to print a number of img html tags by a foreach loop as follows:

```
<?php foreach ( $images as $image ) : ?>  
<img alt="<?php echo $image->alttext ?>" src="<?php echo $image->thumbnailURL ?>" />  
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I would like to wrap a div around every 10 images. The remainder should get a div as well.

I am thinking I need to use `array_chunk`on `$images` and wrap the above in another loop for each chunk. The little bit of math I did to start is as follows:

```
$pics_per_page = 10;  
$imgcount = count($images);  
$num_pages = ceil($imgcount/$pics_per_page);  
$pages = array_chunk($images, $num_pages);
```

How do I proceed from here? How do I use the $images array correctly, if at all, in outputting my HTML?

Forgetting about the array_chunk method, I have the following way, but the array_chunk method seems cleaner.

```
for i from 1 to num_pages:  
echo "<div>"  
j = (i-1) * pics_per_page;  
while j <= i * pics_per_page  
    echo "<img src = "$images[j]->thumbnailURL />";  
endwhile;   
echo "</div>"
```

Thanks for your help in advance,
Sepehr

Answer (score 3):

You are using [`array_chunk` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) wrongly. You just have to specify the size of each chunk:

```
$chunks = array_chunk($images, 10);
```

Then you need a nested `for` (`foreach`) loop:

```
<?php foreach($chunks as $chunk): ?>
    <div class="someClass">
    <?php foreach($chunk as $image): ?>  
        <img alt="<?php echo $image->alttext ?>" src="<?php echo $image->thumbnailURL ?>" />  
    <?php endforeach; ?>
   </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use it without `array_chunk` too.

```
<?php
$imgTot = count($images);

echo '<div>';

for($i=0; $i<$imgTot; $i++)
{
    if ($i % 10 == 0) {
        echo '<div>';
    }

    echo '<img alt="'.$image->alttext.'" src="'.$image->thumbnailURL.'" />';

    if ($i % 10 == 9) {
        echo '</div>';
    }
}

echo '</div>';

?>
```

See the working example here: http://codepad.org/FkdTEH91

Comment: I like the mathy approach here. Thank you. Interesting use of the modulus.